# FIFOがオーバーフローしたときの処理

Tags: arduino, spresense

Arduino環境において、SimpleFIFOでオーバフロー(AS_ATTENTION_SUB_CODE_SIMPLE_FIFO_OVERFLOW)
が発生すると、以降 readFrames()を呼んでも読み込みサイズが０のままとなります。
一旦オーバフローが発生するとFIFOからデータを取り出すことはできなくなるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。
お問い合わせの件について、回答いたします。

FIFOがオーバーフローしたとき、録音処理が停止するため、FIFOからデータの読み出しができなくなります。

以下の手順を行うことで、録音を再開することができます。

"theRecorder->stop();" で、録音処理を終了
"theRecorder->start();" で、録音処理を開始

アンダーフローの場合も同様の処理で復帰させることができます。

どうぞ、よろしくお願いいたします。